# Secure handshake failing during IBM.MQ MQQueueManager on Linux .Net Managed

Tags: .net, linux, openssl, ibm-mq

Trying to change CipherSpec from **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256** to **TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384**.
For TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 I was able to connect to IBMMQ queues.
After changing to TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 I get error:

```
Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan 1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan 1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket.MakeSecuredConnection()
```

Should I configure anything else?
I will add that the app is on Linux, the connection that establishes from the .Net client is managed.

Openssl config:

```
CipherString = @SECLEVEL=1:kEECDH:kRSA:kEDH:kPSK:kDHEPSK:kECDHEPSK:-aDSS:-3DES:!DES:!RC4:!RC2:!IDEA:-SEED:!eNULL:!aNULL:!MD5:-SHA384:-CAMELLIA:-ARIA:-AESCCM8:AES256-SHA256:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!AES256-GCM-SHA384:!AES128-SHA256

Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256

TLS.MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
TLS.MaxProtocol = TLSv1.3

DTLS.MinProtocol = DTLSv1.2
DTLS.MaxProtocol = DTLSv1.2

SignatureAlgorithms = ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:ed25519:ed448:rsa_pss_pss_sha256:rsa_pss_rsae_sha256:rsa_pss_pss_sha384:rsa_pss_rsae_sha384:rsa_pss_pss_sha512:rsa_pss_rsae_sha512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1sh-4
```

I am using **IBMXMSDotnetClient version 9.3.2.**
The error I get after changing the cipher is :

2059 (080B) (RC2059): MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE.

When I use the old one on the server side, a cipher mismatch error is returned (without ssl error), i.e. it shows that I used TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 when I should have used TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

Comment: Are you certain the cipher is supported on the server side?  If you are forcing a specific cipher and nothing works anymore, it indicates that the client and server were not able to negotiate a commun  cipher, pointing to a mismatch configuration between client and server.

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, it is supported by the mq server.  The configuration is weird on the server side because the server itself does not support TLS 1.3 (only TLS 1.2) for handshake, but the server side mq require the TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher. Can I choose a different cipher for handshake and mq ?

Comment: What error do you see on the queue manager logs?   What version of MQ is running on the server?   Please edit and update you question with those details.

Comment: @JoshMc The error that is at the top of my post is just from xms trace, I don't know if that's it?

Comment: The actual error from the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG log would be most helpful but despite that I think I know the issue and posted an answer.

Comment: @JoshMc I believe you may have a point. Could you tell me where I can find the log you mention? I would be very grateful. Might come in handy for some future work.

Comment: This would be on the server where the queue manager runs under the queue manager data directory in a sub directory called errors.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IANA site](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml) `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` is HEX `0x13,0x02`, commonly written `1302`.

You do not mention the version of MQ running on the server but do state it did not support TLS1.3, v9.2 is when MQ started to support TLS1.3 so I'll assume 9.1 or lower.

According to the IBM MQ [Enabling CipherSpecs page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=messages-enabling-cipherspecs) 1302 is not supported.

I suspect you really want the TLS1.2 cipher `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` which is supported and is 009D.

According to this [testssl.sh openssl mapping site](https://testssl.sh/openssl-iana.mapping.html)

1302=openssl cipher `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` which matches the IANA name `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` and is what you specified.

009D=openssl cipher `AES256-GCM-SHA384` which has the IANA name `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` which matches what the IBM MQ queue manger would call it and supports as a TLS1.2 cipher.

I suggest you update your openssl to specify the TLS1.2 cipher `AES256-GCM-SHA384` instead of the TLS1.3 cipher `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sounds like it might help. Will try to test the configuration change on Monday.

Comment: Let me know and please accept this answer if all goes well.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, the log I got from the server:
CommentInsert1(<CHANNEL>)
CommentInsert2(TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
CommentInsert3(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)
AMQ9631E: The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the
required CipherSpec for channel '<CHANNEL'.

Comment: Please update the question with the version of mq on the server side.   Please update with your modified openssl config.  Confirm you configured it for only AES256-GCM-SHA384.

Comment: I'll help you figure out if you help me by providing the additional details requested.

Comment: @KillerQueen any luck fixing it or providing additional information

Comment: Unfortunately, we haven't been able to fix it yet, the tests show that if we pass Cipher with TLS 1.3, we get an error during the handshake because the server does not support TLS 1.3, but if we pass cipher with TLS 1.2, we are rejected by the mq channel. We are trying to find a solution how to pass two different ciphers in connection. I don't know what the server-side mq version is exactly, but I'm sure I accept TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 because another java application that runs on windows has already switched to this cipher.

Comment: We were able to trace the network traffic for this application and handshake is using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 and the connection to the channel is using TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. For java it was enough to update the IBMJCEPlus provider and change the configuration to TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Comment: Can you provide the updated openssl config?   TLS does not negotiate with one cipher then switch to another.   You just need to force openssl on the client to only present the AES256-GCM-SHA384 cipher.

Answer (score 0):

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (equivalent to SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, per IBM SDK documentation) is only available for the TLSv1.2 protocol.

TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 only works for the TLSv1.3 protocol.

[IBM SDK - Cipher Suites Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=suites-cipher)

So, I'd start by confirming that WAS accepts both TLSv1.3 and TLSv1.2 protocols*. If you're using tWAS, check the SSL config (that the app server deploying MQ is using) for the QoP settings. In the admin console, here's an example path:

> Security -> SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations > NodeDefaultSSLSettings > Quality of protection (QoP) settings

* Custom protocol lists were introduced in WASv8.5.5.21 and v9.0.5.11.

Comment: MQ Client supports TLS 1.3, TLS 1.2, MQ Server supports only TLS 1.2. We are unable to force the MQ server to support TLS 1.3.
Such a connection was successfully established from the Windows operating system.

Comment: Will be more specific. The application from which we connect is on linux which supports tls 1.3 and tls 1.2, the server we connect to after messages supports only tls 1.2, but the mq queue server itself requires cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Comment: You are also not using WAS (websphere application server) which this answer is about.   You are not using Java either.   I removed the websphere (WAS) tab to prevent this confusion.